# HtmlAgilityPack : Is there a better way to write this

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I recently started experimenting with HtmlAgilityPack, and the following code is working for what I want to achieve.

But since I just started exploring this, I was wondering if there was a better way then using so many **PreviousSibling** tags

```
var Application_Html = @"https://wiki.profittrailer.com/doku.php?id=application.properties";
        HtmlWeb Internet_Load_Connection = new HtmlWeb();
        var Application_Html_Loaded = Internet_Load_Connection.Load(Application_Html);
        var Wiki_Application_Part_Loaded = Application_Html_Loaded.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class ='dw-content']");
                    
        var divs = Application_Html_Loaded.DocumentNode.Descendants("div").Where(node => node.GetAttributeValue("class", "").Equals("level5")).Where(node => node.ParentNode.GetAttributeValue("class", "").Equals("dw-content")).ToList();
        
        foreach (var s in divs)
        {
            if (s.InnerText.IndexOf(" ") > 0)
            {
                if (s.PreviousSibling.PreviousSibling.Id.Contains("default_api") || s.PreviousSibling.PreviousSibling.Id.Contains("trading_api"))
                {
                    textBox1.AppendText(s.PreviousSibling.PreviousSibling.PreviousSibling.PreviousSibling.PreviousSibling.PreviousSibling.Id + "\n");
                    textBox1.AppendText(s.PreviousSibling.PreviousSibling.PreviousSibling.PreviousSibling.PreviousSibling.PreviousSibling.InnerText + "\n");
                    textBox1.AppendText(s.ChildNodes[3].InnerText + "\n");
                    textBox1.AppendText("\n");

                    textBox1.AppendText(s.PreviousSibling.PreviousSibling.Id + "\n");
                    textBox1.AppendText(s.PreviousSibling.PreviousSibling.InnerText + "\n");
                    textBox1.AppendText(s.ChildNodes[3].InnerText + "\n");
                    textBox1.AppendText("\n");                       
                }
                else
                {
                    textBox1.AppendText(s.PreviousSibling.PreviousSibling.Id + "\n");
                    textBox1.AppendText(s.PreviousSibling.PreviousSibling.InnerText + "\n");
                    textBox1.AppendText(s.ChildNodes[3].InnerText + "\n");
                    textBox1.AppendText("\n");
                }   
            }

        }
```

The idea behind this is to scrape the wiki to see if anything has changed and if so to update/notify me if changes are needed.

Example html piece for reference

```
<h5 id="tradingexchange">trading.exchange</h5>
<div class="level5">
<pre class="code file java">trading.<span class="me1">exchange</span> <span 
class="sy0">=</span> BITTREX</pre>

<p>
Use to set the exchange you want the bot to connect to. Possible values 
(POLONIEX, BITTREX, BINANCE).
Must be in CAPITALS.
</p>
<hr />

</div>
```

all is in the **div class="dw-content"** which I extract first

**h5 id** is needed to check if new option are added

**h5 innertext** is need to check the formatting

**p innertext** to check if the description is updated or not

Comment: _... scrape the wiki to see if anything has changed and if so to update/notify me..._ - IMHO, depends on what your scope on "change" means. e.g. if you're looking to monitor _all_ the "inner text" then maybe giving that a signature for future comparison will suffice (?)

Comment: What I mean by changes is like when new options are added and/or removed also current options the are getting a revision yes or no. If this happens I know I need to update my classes to reflect these changes so I can stil configure my configuration files using a GUI. Right now the only option I have is done by text edting and that is kinda tidious after a while. I'm looking everywhere for descent documentation on htmlagiltypack but it is hard to find. The examples they provide are not very in depth. But that aside. its doing what I want. I just think I am taking the hard route to code it in.